# I would like to implement Product Carousel functionality using Angular without using any libraries

Tags: angular, angular-material, carousel

I would like to implement Carousel functionality using Angular without using any libraries. And make it responsive also

I need like, initially, the first three items should be displayed. Then, If I click Next, then the remaining data items should be displayed one by one, and similarly, if I click on Previous, then previous data items should be displayed
**here is my code in stackblitz**
[stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-services-example-zagzgu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Html:

```
<div class="data-row">
  <div class="data-list show-in-row">
    <ng-container
      *ngFor="let item of products; let index = index; let last = last"
    >
      <div class="data-container">
        <div>{{ item.id }}></div>
        <div>{{ item.price }}></div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="next" title="Next" (click)="next()">Next</div>
```

Ts:

```
 previous() {}

  next() {
    this.products.splice(0, 3);
  }
```

Comment: I don't see any sort of problem being described in regard to the code you've posted, and I don't see any sort of question at all. Can you [edit] to make them clear?

Comment: sir, my problem is I am unable to show only 3 items initially and, then making the previous and next buttons working properly. I want to implement Carousel like e-commerce products Carousel  without using any libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this setShownData() function that gets six items out of our full array based on the current iteration:

```
setShownData(){
    this.products = this.testData.slice(this.iTestData6, (this.iTestData+1)6);
}
```

and  previous and next button click event as follow

```
previous() {
    if(this.iTestData != 0) {
      this.iTestData = this.iTestData - 1;
      this.setShownData();
    }
}

next() {
    if( ((this.iTestData+1) * 6) < this.testData.length){
      this.iTestData = this.iTestData + 1;
      this.setShownData();
    }
}
```